# Async function works when called once but not multiple occasions

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I have used async.waterfall to flatten out a nested function as per the below.

```
function convertPortfolio(trademarks, fn){
    async.waterfall([function(callback){
        groupByCountry(trademarks, callback)
    },
    function(TMsGroupedByCountry, callback){
        addEUTrademarks(TMsGroupedByCountry['EU'], TMsGroupedByCountry, callback)
    },
    function(revisedGroupByCountry, callback){
        groupTrademarksByStatus(revisedGroupByCountry, callback)

    }], function(err, splitByStatus){
        fn(null, splitByStatus);
    })
}
```

Nested alternative

```
function convertPortfolio(trademarks, fn){
    groupByCountry(trademarks, function(err, TMsGroupedByCountry){
        addEUTrademarks(TMsGroupedByCountry['EU'], TMsGroupedByCountry,   function(err, revisedGroupByCountry){
            groupTrademarksByStatus(revisedGroupByCountry, function(err, splitByStatus){
                 fn(null, splitByStatus)
            });
        });
    });
 }
```

Subsequently when I call this function once as part of another function, it works perfectly. However when I attempt to call the function multiple times using a separate value from a forEach call on an array, it fails to work, when the nested version works fine. I am at a loss to explain why this would be the case and in all honesty, I'm not sure where to start. My understanding is that the forEach call should simply mean that each separate value is processed accordingly and closed over so this shouldn't be the issue.

Async function works correctly and returns value in this instance

```
exports.convertPortfolioAndAddToGeoJSON = function(geojson, trademarks, fn){
   convertPortfolio(trademarks, function(err, revisedTMs){
    addToGeoJson(geojson, revisedTMs, function(err, gj){
        fn(null, gj)
      });
   });
}
```

But in this instance the end target object is not populated:

```
exports.convertYearPortfolioAndAddToGeoJSON = function(geojson, trademarks, fn){
  var target = {};
  Object.keys(trademarks).forEach(function(year){
    convertPortfolio(trademarks[year], function(err, revisedTMs){
        addToGeoJson(geojson, revisedTMs, function(err, revisedGeoJSON){
            target[year] = revisedGeoJSON;
            });
        });
    });
    fn(null, target);
  }
```

Using console.log at certain points shows that in the nested example, the return values are logged prior to the target object being logged, whereas with the async.waterfall example, the target object is logged prior to the returned data being available (so I suppose it is not surprising that logging the target results in an empty object).

I thought in each case that the presence of callbacks, would mean that the logging of target would only take place once all previous processed had been completed, but although this appears to be the case with the nested alternative, this is not so with the async version at least when it is called multiple times.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

*UPDATE* Out of interest here's the revised code using async.forEach:

```
exports.convertYearPortfolioAndAddToGeoJSON = function(geojson, trademarks, fn){
  var target = {};
  async.forEach(Object.keys(trademarks), function(year, callback){
    async.waterfall([
        async.apply(convertPortfolio, trademarks[year]),
        function(revisedTMs, callback){
            addToGeoJson(geojson, revisedTMs, callback)
        }], 
        function(err, revisedGeoJSON){
            target[year] = revisedGeoJSON;
            callback()
        })
   }, function(err){
       fn(null, target);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys(trademarks).forEach` is synchronous and doesn't properly track closures/scope. You need to use `async.forEach(Object.keys(trademarks), function(year, callback)....` there, and adjust the async control flow accordingly.

Also just FYI when you have this pattern with a tiny wrapper function:

```
function convertPortfolio(trademarks, fn){
  async.waterfall([function(callback){
    groupByCountry(trademarks, callback)
  },
```

You can use `async.apply` for that boilerplate:

```
function convertPortfolio(trademarks, fn){
  async.waterfall([async.apply(groupByCountry, trademarks),
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks! But if Object.keys is synchronous then why would it work fine as part of the nested code above? I have amended to use async.forEach which works with the nested code but again no joy with async.waterfall. Do extra steps need to be taken (I think this may be part of your comment 'adjust your async control flow accordingly). Perhaps the reason is that I have a flawed understanding of what asynchronous code truly is - I think you just throw in a callback and its asynchronous when it's more nuanced than that...

Comment: You are glossing over details. We are talking about different snippets. Neither your async nor nested snippets above (#1 and #2) use `Object.keys(blah).forEach` which is a synchronous `forEach` (does NOT take a callback). You are making the basic async forEach without callback mistake that trips people up all the time.

Comment: My guess is you are confusing the fact that `Object.keys(foo).forEach` takes an ITERATOR function with the fact that async I/O functions take a CALLBACK function. They are not the same thing. An iterator defines the action to be done on each item in the sequence, a callback indicates to the caller when an async operation has completed.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I now understand the need to provide both the iterator and the callback function as part of async.forEach. Thanks again.